# Thread throwing java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, javafx, arraylist

Every time I run the program this thread throws this exception and I can't seem to find the reason for it. Could someone please try to explain the reason why this happens?

```
package GPS.gpsproject;

import GPS.Model.Event;
import GPS.Model.Vehicle;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import java.util.List;


public class Notify extends Thread {
    private List<Veiculo> vehicles;
    private Controler controler;

    public Notify(List<Veiculo> vehicles, Controlador controler) {
        this.controler= controler;
        this.vehicles= vehicles;   
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            for (Vehicle v : vehicles) {
                for (Event e : v.getEvents()) {
                    if (Duration.between(e.getData().atStartOfDay(), LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay()).toDays() < e.getDiasAntes() && !e.isNotified()) {
                        e.setNotified(true);
                        controler.sendNotification("Notification", e.getDesc());

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
at GPS.gpsproject.Notifica.run(Notify.java:25)
```

The sendNotification() method simply notifies the user of the event

Comment: Is the `vehicles` list modified by some other thread?

Comment: does this compile without errors? class named `Notifica`, constructor named `Notify` (missing return type to be a valid method), compilation unit named `Notify.java`? or being executed without creating `*.class` (Java 11)??

Comment: is `sendNotification()` eventually changing the event list (removing the event) or the vehicles list??  ((Abraços da Alemanha))

Answer (score 1):

When thread2 modifies `ArrayList` (ex, add new elements) while thread1 iterates on it with

`for (Vehicle v : vehicles)`

thread1 will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, which is called fail-fast.

You might want to use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html):

> This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so
>   interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException. The iterator will not reflect
>   additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was
>   created.

Comment: there is no need for a second Thread. The Exception will also be thrown if any of the lists (there is probably also an event list involved) is structurally changed inside the loop, e.g. in `sendNotification()`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yes, that's possible too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `Notifica` and `Notify` refer to the same class (one of them must be a typo). You are passing the `List<Veiculo>` to the constructor of the `Notifica` class. Then you iterate over that `List` in the `run()` method.

Assuming the methods you call inside the nested for loops do not modify the `vehicles` list or any of the inner collections of `Event`s, this means that some other thread must be making structural changes in any of these collections while you are iterating over them.

Since `vehicles` should not be structurally modified while you iterate over it, a possible solution may be to create a copy in the constructor:

```
this.vehicles = new ArrayList<>(vehicles);
```

Note that this will only work if the other threads don't make structural changes in the inner collections of `Event`s belonging to the `Veiculo` instances, since this is a shallow copy.

Comment: I just wonder that the StackTrace also states both: class name and file name

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger perhaps the OP renamed the identifiers (in order to post the question in English), and forgot to rename some of them.